# Jenkins can't execute an existing binary file

Tags: linux, jenkins

Im trying to execute a shell script in my jenkins job  :

```
ls -la /tmp/firefox-portable/firefox
chmod +x /tmp/firefox-portable/firefox
/tmp/firefox-portable/firefox
```

and i got this error message :

```
+ ls -la /tmp/firefox-portable/firefox
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jenkins jenkins 202720 Feb 21 17:47 /tmp/firefox-portable/firefox
+ chmod +x /tmp/firefox-portable/firefox
+ /tmp/firefox-portable/firefox
/tmp/jenkins6967163423349999441.sh: 4: /tmp/jenkins6967163423349999441.sh: /tmp/firefox-portable/firefox: not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

even if this file `/tmp/firefox-portable/firefox` existe, jenkins file can't find it !!

Answer (score 0):

Im trying to executing a 32-bits binary on 64-bit system, this the issue !